# Div's clicking through each other?

Tags: javascript

I have a containing div, which acts as a button all by itself...

When clicked though, I have it setup to expand and reveal more information, at the same time revealing a close button on the top right...

Now, When i click the close button, the close function executes, but also the div's onclick to open, so the end result is, well... Nothing happens...

Lol...

The fiddle example isn't working either, and I'm near the end of my wits...

http://jsfiddle.net/VeyeY/5/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could either return false from the onclick to close the div. That will make sure that the click event is not propagated.

Another solution would be to call `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` on the event itself. That will also make sure that the event does not go on.

### Edit:

In all the Events that happens ( onclick, onchange, onmouseover, etc ) there is always an event variable possible that you can either ignore if you want to, or extract information from. In your example I think the easiest way to work with the event variable would be to do something like this:

```
<div id="inner" onclick="toggle(false); event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();">
```

Now this is a bit ugly to look at and you really dont want to deal with this in the html markup either so another option would be to pass the event variable to your function like this:

```
<div id="inner" onclick="toggle(event, false)">
```

and then in the javascript:

```
function toggle(event, x){
    // Do your thing

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

There are a lot of things you could do with the event variable. For example, instead of passing true or false to your function, you could check which node that originated the event like this:

```
if(event.originalTarget.id == "inner"){
    // Inner was clicked
}else if(event.originalTarget.id == "outer"){
    // Outer was clicked
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... This sounds interesting... I'm a JS novice, so these two are new... Mind explaining (or pointing me to an explanation) of what you're suggesting here?

Comment: That was descriptive... Thank you mate... :-)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**
You can:

1. Put a `margin-top` on `#inner`  so the user won't click both simultaneously (or an offset of some kind from the top edge of `#outer`).  *(Update: rejected, CSS solution)*
2. Or, fire a different function for each `div`, like `innerToggle()` and `outerToggle()`.  This way you can even call one, from the other. *(Update: Fiddled [here](http://jsfiddle.net/steve/aXa49/), led to solution 2a.)*

   *2a. Another way to do it is just fire the event for `#outer` only?  If `#inner` is clicked, the event will bubble up and `#outer` will fire a toggle, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/steve/JQJyP/).*
3. Or, disable the click event for one or the other as required. *(Update: See @DanneMarne's solution.)*
4. Or, set a custom property on each object, such as `$('outer').toggled = false` which will record the current state of each object. *(Update: Never mind, not very helpful).*

*Update: So, after a bit of testing, I'd go with 2a.*

Comment: First off, awesome take on answering a question with choices in my possible course of action... With regards to my problem though, the first choice isn't feasible (the css has me by the neck, and I have no intentions of fattening her up anymore), I tried different functions, and I still ended up with the same thing... Disabling the click by removing the 'onclick' attribute? And I'm still new to JS, so jQuery is way over me... :-p

Comment: I explored the ideas in the context of your example, some good some bad.  It looks like you don't need to fire an `onclick` for `#inner`, since the close button is located in `#outer` anyway.  Also I confirm that Javascript is behaving strangely on JSFiddle, probably a simple setting that I'm too lazy to fix.  :)

Comment: But you see, lets say that there's a box, when you click on this box, it expands and reveals more information, and also reveals a small close button on the top right... Now, clicking this close button (I choose to use a Div for whatever reason, call it a challenge), will also trigger the parent div's onclick action, hence not closing the box... :-( If I rely solely on the parent's toggle, then clicking anywhere will result in the box closing...

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the DIVs click function after revealing. And you can re-enable that click function when close button is pressed.

Comment: You see, what I did was, when the outer div is clicked, I go through the toggle process, and I REMOVE the onclick property for the outer div... So there's only a single event firing from the inner div, yeah? (outer.removeAttribute('onclick')), I obviously have to add the attribute again after I click the inner div, but what happens is, that as soon as the inner div gets clicked, the outer gets its click back, and that fires too, and I end up in the same place where I started from... Frustrating... :-p